# non-parametric estimation of competing risks model

Tags: survival, nonparametric, econometrics, mixed-model, competing-risks

Assume that our sample is composed by people that start from state `A` that are at risk of ending at state `B1` or `B2`.
A typical application is when individuals are ill and can either get worse off and eventually die, or directly die.
An alternative situation is when unemployed individuals either start a training program (supposedly able to increas their chance to get a job) or directly find a job.

One way to model this situation is to set up a semi-parametric competing risks model that takes into account unobserved heterogeneity (*mixed proportional hazard* model), either in continuous time or in discrete time.

My question concerns the modeling strategy. Are you aware of **fully non-parametric** models that allows to study the above situation?